# Moving average by column / year - python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, moving-average

I need to built a moving average over column "total_medals" by country [noc] for all previous years - my daata looks like:

```
 medal     Bronze  Gold  Medal  Silver  **total_medals**
    noc year                                           
    ALG 1984     2.0   NaN    NaN     NaN           2.0
        1992     4.0   2.0    NaN     NaN           6.0
        1996     2.0   1.0            4.0           7.0
    ANZ 1984     2.0  15.0    NaN     2.0          19.0
        1992     3.0   5.0    NaN     2.0          10.0
        1996     1.0   2.0            2.0           5.0
    ARG 1984     2.0   6.0    NaN     3.0          11.0
        1992     5.0   3.0    NaN    24.0          32.0
        1992     3.0   7.0    NaN     5.0          15.0
```

I want to have a moving average per country and year (i.e. for ALG: 1984 Avg (total_medals)=2.0; 1992 Avg(total_medals) = (2.0+6.0)/2 = 4.0; 1996 Acg(total_medals) = (2.0+6.0+7.0)/3 = 5.0) - moving average should appear in new column (next to total_medals).

Additionally, for each country & year combination new column called "performance" should be the fraction of "total_medals" divided by "moving average"

Comment: Tell me if it works

Comment: I am glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample dataframe**:

```
print(df)

          medal  Bronze  Gold  Medal  Silver 
noc year                                     
ALG 1984    2.0     NaN   NaN    NaN     2.0 
    1992    4.0     2.0   NaN    NaN     6.0 
    1996    2.0     1.0   NaN    4.0     7.0 
ANZ 1984    2.0    15.0   NaN    2.0    19.0 
    1992    3.0     5.0   NaN    2.0    10.0 
    1996    1.0     2.0   NaN    2.0     5.0 
ARG 1984    2.0     6.0   NaN    3.0    11.0 
    1992    5.0     3.0   NaN   24.0    32.0 
    1992    3.0     7.0   NaN    5.0    15.0
```

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `expanding`:

```
df['total_mean']=df.groupby(level=0,sort=False).Silver.apply(lambda x: x.expanding(1).mean())
print(df)

          medal  Bronze  Gold  Medal  Silver  total_medals 
noc year                                                 
ALG 1984    2.0     NaN   NaN    NaN     2.0    2.000000 
    1992    4.0     2.0   NaN    NaN     6.0    4.000000 
    1996    2.0     1.0   NaN    4.0     7.0    5.000000 
ANZ 1984    2.0    15.0   NaN    2.0    19.0   19.000000 
    1992    3.0     5.0   NaN    2.0    10.0   14.500000 
    1996    1.0     2.0   NaN    2.0     5.0   11.333333 
ARG 1984    2.0     6.0   NaN    3.0    11.0   11.000000 
    1992    5.0     3.0   NaN   24.0    32.0   21.500000 
    1992    3.0     7.0   NaN    5.0    15.0   19.333333
```

---

**bonze lagged**

```
s=df.groupby('noc').apply(lambda x: x['Bronze']/x['total_medals'].shift())
s.index=s.index.droplevel()
df['bronze_lagged']=s
```

---

**You could create a function for this...**

```
def lagged_medals(type_of_medal):
    s=df.groupby('noc').apply(lambda x: x[type_of_medal]/x['total_medals'].shift())
    s.index=s.index.droplevel()
    df[f'{type_of_medal}_lagged']=s

lagged_medals('Silver')
#print(df)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, in fact i need the moving average of 'medal' , can you specifiy this? Why is there a 'NaN' for each first year? There should be an value as there is also a value on 'medal'

Comment: I think the NaN's are because of `x.expanding(2)`. If you use `x.expanding(1)` they will not appear.

Comment: You need expand(1) as @Erfan suggestd. 
I thought I should use the silver column but you can perform the operation on other columns. Simply change the label.

Comment: `df['total_mean']=df.groupby(level=0,sort=False).medals.apply(lambda x: x.expanding(1).mean())`

Comment: `df.groupby('noc').expanding(1).mean()` seems to work fine.

Comment: just one more question: how can I construct a 'lagged variable' of 'total medals' per country and assign this to new column? E.g. share of this years bronze medals on last years 'total medals' (Example for ALG: 1996: 1.0 (Bronze medals) / 4.0 (1992 'total_medals')?

Comment: What would be the expected output for ANZ?

Comment: Output for ANZ would be a new column "share of bronze_lagged" with the following value: 1984: No value (since no value for total medals existing before 1984); 1992: 5(bronze medals in 1992) / 19 (total medals in 1984) = 0.263158; 1996: 2 (bronze medals in 1996) / 14.5 (total medals in 1992) = 0.13793